# Computer is using way more RAM than is should

Tags: memory, performance

Computer Specs"
2 X 8GB of RAM
Intel Core i7-6800k
GTX 1070

In the past couple of months, it has felt like my RAM has been decreasing, but every time I check Task Manager it still says I have 16GB. But today I was messing around a bit more in Task Manager and I noticed if I change the Memory display column from value to percent it will tell me that a program using 500MB is also using 20% of my RAM putting my total ram at 2.5GB, not 16GB. Now I know that's not true because I can see in Task Manager that I'm using 4GB at some points.

This may be unrelated but my internet speed has also experienced a decline in the same period.

Also, note all 3 screenshots where taken within a minute while nothing was loading.

[RamMap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGYOK.png)
[Task Manager (Processes)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWDJy.png)
[Task Manager (Performance)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKsVl.png)

Comment: Task Manager doesn’t have a bug that critical.  Your screenshots indicate you have 16 GB system memory.  Your screenshots also don’t display the percentages.  Suspect there is something else actually going on

Comment: Worth pointing out you have 3 GB cached and 3 GB the rest is basically actively being used by applications.  Your system is actively using 12 GB of memory which is 80% of 16 GB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at your screenshot, you can see your **Non-paged pool** is extremely large, nearly half your ram.  This represents memory used by the kernel and drivers that is vital and has to remain in ram, unable to be paged out to make space.  As a result your system may be spending more time swapping applications in and out of the page file which can cause a system to feel slower.

Generally this should only be a small amount of ram, around 200MB to 500MB in my experience. Having a large value such as you do is indicative of a memory leak, likely in a driver.  Check for driver updates for your system and make sure they are all up to date.

Some additional details and troubleshooting steps can be found here: [Huge Memory Usage in Non-Paged Pool in Windows](http://woshub.com/huge-memory-usage-non-paged-pool-windows/)

Comment: Thanks that seemed to have solevd it